# Increase inter-line space in a table and index dimension or position

Tags: tables

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{shock wave}\\
\hline
Left wave & Right wave\\
\hline
$U-u_I+\mathlarger{\frac{P-p_I}{a_I}}=0$ & $U-u_{II}+\mathlarger{\frac{P-p_{II}}{a_{II}}}=0,$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: table I get]

But I would like to get something like this:

[image: table I'd like to get]

That is, I would like that the P and the denominator indices didn't touch the `\hline`; and that the index I and II were more proportioned (smaller and lowed-down).

Comment: Your example generates `! Undefined control sequence. l.12 $U-u_I+\mathlarger`

Comment: You forgot include in the code the package `relsize` that provides the `\mathlarger` command. Other possibility is to load the package `amsmath` and use `\dfrac{}{}` instead of `\frac{}{}`

Comment: I edited my answer to include a new solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must increase the space between rows using something like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`, `1.5` is a scale factor and can be changed by other.

However this doesn't work for the row where the equations are. So that you must include a command like `\vphantom{$\Biggl(\Biggr)$}` at begin of the row to simulate the height of a great parenthesis and to reserve the necessary space.

If indexes seem very large you can reduce its size using `\scriptscriptstyle` like in `$p_{\scriptscriptstyle II}$` that produces [image] or simulate an exponent to go down the level of the subscript, like `$a_{II}^{\phantom{2}}$` that produces [image] instead of [image].

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{shock wave}\\
\hline
Left wave & Right wave\\
\hline
 \vphantom{$\Biggl(\Biggr)$} $U-u_I+\dfrac{P-p_I}{a_I}=0$ & $U-u_{II}+\dfrac{P-p_{II}}{a_{II}}=0,$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]

### Other solution

Other way is using the package [`cellspace`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cellspace/cellspace.pdf) created specifically to solve this problem.  It provides new *column specifiers* prepending a `S` to the usual ones. The distance *above* and *below* of the cell is controled by the length parameters `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`. These lengths are `1pt` by default which looks as separate, but they can be changed with `\setlength`.

Load the package `\usepackage{cellspace}`, change the *column specifiers* in `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}` by `\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}` and use something like

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{1ex}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{1ex}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{shock wave}\\
\hline
Left wave & Right wave\\
\hline
$U-u_I+\dfrac{P-p_I}{a_I}=0$ & $U-u_{II}+\dfrac{P-p_{II}}{a_{II}}=0,$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and you will get a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the beautiful `booktabs`-package:
ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf

The `booktabs`-package provides the command `\addlinespace` which does exactly what you need.

I would recommand to also read the rest of the documentation, very good hints for making good looking tables.